# Google Play Developer processing time

Tags: google-play

For the last 72 hours, my Google Wallet payment for the Google Play developer program has shown as "Your purchase is processing". I understand it can take up to 48 hours, but this is an entire day after their worst-case scenario for processing time.

I contacted Google Play using their help pages, not expecting an answer back until this week, with the problem hopefully resolving itself in the meantime. However, a day later instead of a reply (Which i wasn't expecting yet), they instead send me a survey, asking how their support was. Support I never received.

Does anyone know how to contact Google Play directly? While it's only $25, it's $25 that's been sent to google, and have received nothing in return. Google Wallet payments for apps have all gone through (Status: Your purchase is complete). Not sure why this is being help up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Google [Android Developer - Known Issues](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/known-issues/24493) page

> ### Unable to complete Google Play Android Developer Account Registration
>
> We've received reports that some developers are currently unable to
>   complete their developer account registration. Please be advised that
>   certain transactions may take up to 48 hours to be processed by Google
>   Checkout system. Until your transaction is fully processed by Google
>   Checkout system, you won't be able to publish applications.
>
> Please wait for 48 hours. If you still see the 'Your registration is
>   being processed...' banner in your Google Play Developer Console after
>   48 hours from the moment you placed the transaction, please contact
>   Google Wallet Team.

If it takes longer than 48h, [Report Google Play Developer Registration or Account Issue](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/dev_registration)